# Sorting an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an array `$array`

```
$array =>
(
  ['name'] => (
                 "Ronaldo","Ribery","Bale","Messi"
               ),
  ['rank'] => (
                2,4,1,3
              )
)
```

Now How can i sort the array `DESC` using `rank` field along with the `name`
Expected output ->

```
$array =>
(
  ['name'] => (
                 "Ribery","Messi","Ronaldo","Bale"
               ),
  ['rank'] => (
                4,3,2,1
              )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A valid use for oft-misunderstood [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
$array = [
  'name' => ["Ronaldo","Ribery","Bale","Messi"],
  'rank' => [2,4,1,3]
];
array_multisort(
    $array['rank'], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,
    $array['name'], SORT_ASC,  SORT_STRING
);
var_dump($array);
```

---

```
array(2) {
  'name' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "Ribery"
    [1] =>
    string(5) "Messi"
    [2] =>                                                                                                                                                            
    string(7) "Ronaldo"                                                                                                                                               
    [3] =>                                                                                                                                                            
    string(4) "Bale"                                                                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                                                   
  'rank' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    int(4)
    [1] =>
    int(3)
    [2] =>
    int(2)
    [3] =>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [php article](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) also if you want your two arrays to have a relation than you could better write it like this:

```
array(
    array(
        name => 'Messi',
        rank => 4,
    ),
    etc..
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your data structure to be able to work with objects?

```
class Player {
    public $name; // would be better as private and add getters
    public $rank;

    public function __construct($name, $rank) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->rank = $rank;
    }
}
```

Then fill your array (I'm not familiar with soccer):

```
$players = [   // or array(...) if you are using older PHP
    new Player('Foo', 3),
    new Player('Bar', 1),
    new Player('FooBar', 2)
];
```

Then you can use the regular sort:

```
// or a function name, if using older PHP
usort($players, function (Player $a, Player $b) { 
    if ($a->rank == $b->rank) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->rank < $b->rank) ? -1 : 1;
});
```